# Unit Testing ADF Pipeline with SpecFlow

Tags: c#, asp.net, specflow, azure-data-factory

I'm starting off with SpecFlow to test my Azure Data Factory pipelines. I'm using VS 2019 & .NET Framework 4.7.2. When I try to run my test, it starts executing and then completes instantaneously. I've also observed that it doesn't hit the breakpoints which I've placed in the `feature file` as well as in the `binding`. This is my `packages.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory" version="4.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" version="15.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.20" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.19" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" version="15.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="SpecRun.Runner" version="3.2.22" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="SpecRun.SpecFlow.2-4-0" version="3.2.22" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

When I checked my log file, I could find this line in the log file that got generated: `No tests executed (activation needed)`. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong here? Note that my solution is building properly.

PFB the entire log for your reference:

```
2020-04-21T23:25:19.8268118+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;SpecFlow+Runner execution started
2020-04-21T23:25:19.8268118+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;SpecFlow+Runner 3.2.22 in Framework clr40 in x86 mode execution started
2020-04-21T23:25:19.8268118+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;TestAdapter Location: C:\Users\ddc\source\repos\ADF.UnitTest\packages\SpecRun.Runner.3.2.22\tools\net45\TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll
2020-04-21T23:25:20.0532065+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;SpecRun: running tests in C:\Users\ddc\source\repos\ADF.UnitTest\ADF.UnitTest\bin\Debug\ADF.UnitTest.dll
2020-04-21T23:25:20.0532065+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Output folder configured to "C:\Users\ddc\source\repos\ADF.UnitTest\TestResults" (default)
2020-04-21T23:25:20.0542043+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Profile: ADF.UnitTest
2020-04-21T23:25:20.1309989+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Log file path: C:\Users\ddc\source\repos\ADF.UnitTest\TestResults\ADF.UnitTest_ADF.UnitTest_2020-04-21T232520.log
2020-04-21T23:25:20.1429665+05:30;Thread#14;Info;Checking activation
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6090483+05:30;Thread#14;Error;No tests executed (activation needed)
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6339842+05:30:Total: 0
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6369734+05:30:Succeeded: 0
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6369734+05:30:Ignored: 0
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6369734+05:30:Pending: 0
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6379706+05:30:Skipped: 0
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6379706+05:30:Failed: 0
2020-04-21T23:25:21.6449520+05:30;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Adding attachments to VSTest
========== End of log file ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue pop up when I updated my SpecFlow NuGet packages.  SpecFlow now requires you to setup an account via a Microsoft account.

Check the Output from the tests in Visual Studio and there should be a link to activate an account.  See the documentation here: https://specflow.org/2020/introducing-the-specflow-account/